# Анимация прыжка персонажа на блок

Tags: javascript, анимация, разработка-игр

У меня получилось сделать так, чтобы Джек запрыгивал на блок, но никак не получается осуществить его падение, если он с этого блока сходит. Походу, само запрыгивание сделано не очень правильно. Его реализация находится в последней функции moveMan

```js
    const canvasFon = document.getElementById('fon');
    let ctxFon = canvasFon.getContext('2d');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('field');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctxFon.fillStyle = 'black';
    let secondLineX = 250,
        thirdLineY = 450,
        secondWidth = 428;
    ctxFon.fillRect(secondLineX, thirdLineY, secondWidth, 25);

    function jack() {
        let sprite = new Image();
        sprite.src = 'https://www.emu-land.net/forum/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=77145.0;attach=175283;image';
        let tick_count = 0,
            rightPressed = false, //определение нажатых кнопак, изначальное значение false, так как кнопки не нажаты
            leftPressed = false,
            jackWidth = 34, //ширина, высота
            jackHeight = 89,
            sx = 0,
            dx = 100, //координаты
            dy = canvas.height - jackHeight - 15,
            jumpPressed = false,
            jumpCount = 0,
            jumpLength = 75,//длина прыжка по горизонтали
            jumpHeight = 0;//высота прыжка
        sprite.onload = function () { //отрисовка стоящего сузуки при загрузке, его стандартное состояние
            stayMan(dy);
        };

        function stayMan(y) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(sprite, 50, 178, 39, 89, dx, y, jackWidth, jackHeight);
        }

        function jumpMan() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(sprite, 0, 355, 57, 89, dx, dy - jumpHeight, 57, jackHeight);
        }

        function drawMan() { //отрисовка мальчика во время движения
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);//очистка канваса
            sx = (sx === 510 ? 0 : sx + 34); //переброс в начало
            ctx.drawImage(sprite, sx, 0, 32, 89, dx, dy, jackWidth, jackHeight);//отображение первого спрайта
        }

        function forKeydown(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 32) jumpPressed = true; //пробел
            if (e.keyCode === 37) leftPressed = true; //стрелочка лево
            if (e.keyCode === 39) rightPressed = true;//стрелочка право
        }

        function forKeyup(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 37) {
                leftPressed = false;
                stayMan(dy);
            }
            if (e.keyCode === 39) {
                rightPressed = false;
                stayMan(dy);
            }
        }

        document.addEventListener('keydown', forKeydown, false);
        document.addEventListener('keyup', forKeyup, false);


        function moveMan() {
            if (rightPressed && dx < canvas.width - jackWidth) {
                tick();
                dx += 4
            }
            if (leftPressed && dx > 0) {
                tick();
                dx -= 4
            }
            if (jumpPressed) {
                jumpCount++;
                jumpHeight = 2 * jumpLength * Math.sin(Math.PI * jumpCount / jumpLength); //отнимается от dy, значит мальчик становится выше
                jumpMan();
            }

            //отрабатывает прыжок на блок!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            if ((dy - jumpHeight + jackHeight <= thirdLineY) && ((dx + 45 >= secondLineX) && (dx - 45 + jackWidth) <= (secondLineX + secondWidth))) {
                if((dx + 45 <= secondLineX)){
                    dy = canvas.height - jackHeight - 15;
                }
                jumpCount = 0;
                jumpPressed = false;
                jumpHeight = -75;
                dy = thirdLineY - jackHeight + 15;
                stayMan(thirdLineY - jackHeight + 15);
   
            }

            if (jumpCount > jumpLength) {
                jumpCount = 0;
                jumpPressed = false;
                jumpHeight = 0; //ничего не отнимается, значит возвращается в исходную позицию
                stayMan(dy);
            }
        }

        setInterval(moveMan, 10);

        function tick() {
            if (tick_count > 10) { //количвество отрисованных кадров, влияние на скорость
                tick_count = 0;
                drawMan(dy);
            }
            tick_count += 1;
        }
    }

    jack();
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
<canvas id="fon" style="position: absolute" width="928" height="600"></canvas>
<canvas id="field" width="928" height="600" style="position: absolute">hi</canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: обычно для таких вещей вводят имитацию физики + алгоритм пересечения предметов

Comment: @ThisMan а без этого никак? Что конкретно можно использовать, а то я вообще не понимаю, как всякие движки работают

Comment: вам нужно определять, находится ли игрок на поверхности и если нет, то пускай падает в низ, пока не достигнет поверхности ( любой )

Comment: при этому нужно учитывать фазу прыжка, что бы когда прыгали, проверка не осуществлялась

Comment: Если ваша основная задача - создание игры, а не движка, то используйте готовый движок, например phaser. Там [уже есть](http://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/physics/arcade/collider-1) и физика, и коллизии.

Answer (score 1):

У вас пока ничего не написано про падение Джека с блока (если я правильно понял). Надо в вашем игровом цикле `moveMan` проверять падает ли Джек (для этого надо проверить, что у него под ногами пусто) и отключать другие возможности пока он не перестанет падать, отнимая его высоту.

Определение есть ли что-то под ногами Джека и есть проверка коллизий ("алгоритм пересечения предметов") о котором вам говорят в комментариях. Вы такую проверку уже делаете, когда реализуете остановку прыжка Джека на платформе (сравниваете координаты Джека и платформы).

Если вы структурируете свой код, то сможете справится со сложностью таких взаимодействий. Например все блоки (в том числе и пол, на котором Джек стоит в самом низу) можно поместить в массив и потом на каждой итерации цикла проверять не упёрся ли Джек в один из них. Код для всех блоков будет одинаковый (отличаются только их координаты) и ваш Джек сможет запрыгивать не на один, а на любое количество блоков.

Пробуйте и у вас получится.

Answer (score 0):

Вычисляйте пересечение Джека с препятствиями. Скорее всего вам придётся таки познакомиться с суммой Минковского.

Понятная статья на хабре - "[Как Минковский во Flappy Bird играл](https://habr.com/ru/post/217645/)", и менее понятная в вики - "[Сумма Минковского](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)".

[image: Джек]